# How can I use a single query to list aggregate enumerated values of a single field?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, enumeration

The title is a bit convoluted. Here's a concrete example. I have two tables:

```
+-------------+--------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type                           | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| event       | varchar(100)                   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| sport       | varchar(100)                   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| athleteCode | char(10)                       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| medal       | enum('GOLD','SILVER','BRONZE') | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name    | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| code    | char(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| country | varchar(100) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The first table is an medals table. The second table is an athlete table. The two tables are related via `medals.athleteCode` and `athlete.code`. I want to be able to list out a query that displays the following information:

`COUNTRY | GOLD | SILVER | BRONZE | TOTAL`

The only way that I've been able to do it so far is to use this query:

```
SELECT country, medal, COUNT(medal) as count  
    FROM athletes, medals  
    WHERE athletes.code=medals.athleteCode  
    GROUP BY country, medal  
    ORDER BY country, medal;
```

But after I do this query I still have to process the query (via PHP) because this only gets me every country per medal type (i.e. All of China's golds, all of China's silvers, all of China's bronzes, etc). Is there a way to create a query where each record (i.e. row) of the query is: `COUNTRY | GOLDS | SILVERS | BRONZES | TOTAL`? I looked at `COUNT()` but I'm not really sure how to use it.

---

#### 2012.08.17

@"habib zare"'s solution is really close. Here's my tweak of it:

```
SELECT country, 
(SELECT count(*) FROM medals WHERE a.code=m.athleteCode AND medal='Gold') AS Gold,
(SELECT count(*) FROM medals WHERE a.code=m.athleteCode AND medal='Silver') AS Silver,
(SELECT count(*) FROM medals WHERE a.code=m.athleteCode AND medal='Bronze') AS Bronze,
(SELECT count(*) FROM medals WHERE a.code=m.athleteCode) AS Total
FROM medals m JOIN athletes a
ON m.athleteCode=a.code
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY country, Gold DESC, Silver DESC, Bronze DESC
```

The problem is that the secondary `SELECT` statements need to select based on the country; that is I need something like:

```
SELECT country AS Country,
(SELECT count(*) FROM medals WHERE a.code=m.athleteCode AND medal='Gold' AND a.country=Country) AS Gold,
```

Comment: can we have  a look at your sample data please

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL Server `SUM(CASE WHEN medal = 'GOLD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GOLDS` can be used with `GROUP BY country`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use OUTER APPLY if you are using MSSQL:

Sample:

```
SELECT Country
  ,Gold = ISNULL(GoldMedals.MedalCount,0)
  ,Total = ISNULL(TotalMedals.MedalCount,0) 
FROM athletes
  OUTER APPLY (
     SELECT MedalCount = COUNT(*)
     FROM medals
     WHERE medals.athletescode = atheletes.medalsathleteCode
       AND medals.Type = 'Gold'
   ) GoldMedals
   OUTER APPLY (
     SELECT MedalCount = COUNT(*)
     FROM medals
     WHERE medals.athletescode = atheletes.medalsathleteCode
    ) TotalMedals   
GROUP BY country
```

You'll probably need to add SUM instead of ISNULL but I didn't really test this code, so use it as is...

Answer (score 0):

i dont understand what you want but i think you want this :

medals : 
medal   event   sport   athleteCode
Gold    jh  swim       1

Bronze  dfg ert 2

Gold    fg  err 1

Silver  as  erf 4

Bronze  as  erf 5

Gold    df  dfg 6

Gold    sdds    tekvando    3

Bronze  df  jh  1

Bronze  yy  jh  1

Silver  ik  as  1

Silver  shj jsg 3

Silver  shj jsg 5

Silver  sjdk    hgj 5

Silver  wuytu   wopow   5

Silver  wuytu   wopow   6

Silver  wuytu   wopow   6

and

athlete :

name    code    country

habib   1   iran

ahmad   2   azerbaijan

mehmad  3   turkey

so  4   iran

ghg 5   azerbaijan

yewtuuy 6   azerbaijan

my query:

```
SELECT country,name,
(select count(*) from medals where athleteCode=m.athleteCode and medal='Gold') as Gold,
(select count(*) from medals where athleteCode=m.athleteCode and medal='Silver') as Silver,
(select count(*) from medals where athleteCode=m.athleteCode and medal='Bronze') as Bronze,
(select count(*) from medals where athleteCode=m.athleteCode) as Total
FROM medals m join athletes a
on m.athleteCode=a.code
group by country,code
order by country,Gold desc,Silver desc,Bronze desc
```

the result :

country name    Gold    Silver  Bronze  Total

azerbaijan  yewtuuy 1   2   0   3

azerbaijan  ghg 0   3   1   4

azerbaijan  ahmad   0   0   1   1

iran    habib   2   1   2   5

iran    so  0   1   0   1

turkey  mehmad  1   1   0   2

Comment: This is really close. See my edit in the question to see what I tweaked and where the problems were.